# Can i paint with graphics g on a Jpanel and if i can how does it work?

Tags: java, swing

Can i paint with graphics g on a Jpanel and if i can how does it work?

```
    JPanel Game = new JPanel();
    Game.setLayout(null);
    Game.setLocation(0,0);
    Game.setSize(500,700);
    Game.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    Game.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
```

how can i add paintcomponent on this Jpanel

Comment: _"how can i add paintcomponent on this Jpanel"_ - `MyPanel extends JPanel`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for custom painting you have to subclass your `JPanel` then you have to override `paintComponent` calling in first line `super.paintComponent(..)`.

Example :

```
JPanel game = new JPanel(){
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
          super.paintComponent(g);
          //custom painting here
    }
};
//game.setLayout(null); don't use null layout 
game.setLocation(0,0);
game.setSize(500,700);
game.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
game.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
```

Read more in [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) | [Performing custom painting in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Note: In java variable's name start with lower-case following a camel style by [convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html). So `Game` should be `game`.

Comment: +1 for the simple example, link to the tutorial and correcting the "game" variable name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement your own custom painting on a component you will have to make your own class which extends that component. You will start with something like

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //Add your custom painting here
    } 
}
```

You can then use that panel with something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? " + SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Demo");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    f.add(new MyPanel());
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: -1, class names should start with an upper case character. The OP is already naming the "Game" variable incorrectly. Proper naming standards should be encouraged.

Comment: Maybe it was a bit harsh but you had to enter the class name twice in the example code. So it was something that was done purposely. I had no way on knowing if that was the way you normally code or not. As I suggested in my comment you did not correct the variable name either and I did not want to give the OP the impression that it is ok to use random naming conventions. If the OP is going to post question on the forum then the code should be in a format that is readable.